# printing the hex value of a character in bash

Tags: bash

In C, `printf ("%2X\n", 'A');` prints `41`.

In bash, `printf "%2X\n" 'A'` prints `bash: printf: A: invalid number`.

How can I print `41` using `printf` in `bash` like in C ?

Please do not recommend using external tools like `od` because this is too slow: I'm seeking a bash-internal method.

Comment: Use **printf "%X\n" \"A\"** -- note, ASCII, not Unicode. See https://blog.fpmurphy.com/2010/12/shell-script-print-hexadecimal-representation-of-string.html See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12273/in-bash-how-can-i-convert-a-unicode-codepoint-0-9a-f-into-a-printable-charact for converse

Comment: @DrMoishePippik What do you mean by "ASCII, not Unicode"? Do you actually mean "Unicode, not UTF-8" or so?

Comment: Apologies for the ancient notation -- yes, ASCII means UTF-8, i.e., single-byte character, here.

Comment: Thank you, @DrMoishePippik, that works, but how is that feature called ?

Would you like to add an answer which I could accept ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [`printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-printf) in the bash manual, you'll find:

> Arguments to **non-string format specifiers** are treated as C language constants, except that a leading plus or minus sign is allowed, and **if the leading character is a single or double quote, the value is the ASCII value of the following character.**

(my emphasis)

---

These shell functions encapsulate char_to_hex and hex_to_char. Function names stolen from perl

```sh
# ord: the ascii value of a character
# $ ord "A" #=> 65
#
ord() {
    printf "%d" "\"$1"
}

# chr: the character represented by the given ASCII decimal value
# $ chr 65 #=> A
#
chr() {
    printf "\x$(printf "%x" "$1")"
}
```

Then:

```bsh
$ ord A
65
$ printf '%02X\n' "$(ord A)"
41
```

Comment: Do you know how that feature is called ?

Comment: I don't know if that has a particular name.

Answer (score 3):

Though short, @Juergen comments that this answers his question. Use the following:

`printf "%X\n" \"A\"`

Note, this provides the single-byte ("ASCII", UTF-8) charcter code. See the [Unix & Linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12273/in-bash-how-can-i-convert-a-unicode-codepoint-0-9a-f-into-a-printable-charact) for more on char -> hex value and the converse, hex -> char, using bash shell and/or python.

Comment: Rather it provides the *codepoint* (ASCII, or actually Unicode, a superset of ASCII), which *may not* be the byte(s) in hex of the character encoded in UTF-8 or so. (In the words, it *does not always* provide the same result given in `echo -n X | hexdump -C`, like when X is not a character covered by ASCII but e.g. a CJK character.) It's like `hex(ord("X"))` vs `"X".encode("utf-8")` in Python 3.

Comment: @TomYan, yes, it provides the codepoint. Example: ```LANG=en_US.utf-8 bash -c "printf '%2X\n' \$'\"\\u1e20'"``` prints `1E20`, not only a single byte.